# Find and Replace a batch file using DOS

Tags: windows, batch-file, dos

This is what i need.

Lets say there is a file temp.txt
Lets say temp.txt has the following content :

```
name=@name
age=@age
email=@email
```

And my batch file create.bat should ask for the three parameters as input from the user,
and then replace the temp.txt with the respective values.

Say.

```
Pls enter your name:Tom
Tom - Confirm Y/N: Y
<<now anywhere the temp.txt says @name, it is replace by Tom>>
```

Please help me write a script for this??

Thanks,
Naveen.

Answer (score 0):

```
rem @echo off

setlocal enabledelayedexpansion enableextensions

rem Don't use the same file name for both here
set InputFile=temp.txt
set OutputFile=temp2.txt

call :ask name name
call :ask age age
call :ask "e-Mail address" email

del %OutputFile% 1>nul 2>&1
for /f "delims=" %%l in (%InputFile%) do (
    set Line=%%l
    set Line=!Line:@name=%name%!
    set Line=!Line:@age=%age%!
    set Line=!Line:@email=%email%!
    >>%OutputFile% echo.!Line!
)

goto :eof

rem :ask "placeholder title" variable_name
:ask
set /p %2=Please enter your %~1: 
choice /M "!%2! - Confirm"
if errorlevel 2 goto ask
goto :eof
```